# Displaying IDA names in x64dbg or OllyDbg

Tags: ida, ollydbg, debuggers, x64dbg

I like x64dbg, but, without seeing IDA's names, it's hard to keep track of all the hex.  Is there any way to export IDA's names into x64dbg (ideally contiuously)

Comment: There are plugins to sync the IDA view with x64dbg - https://github.com/quarkslab/qb-sync, https://github.com/tmr232/ret-sync

Comment: why not just debug in IDA?

Answer (score 9):

The plugin labeless (https://github.com/a1ext/labeless) was created for exactly this purpose. You can now also use x64dbgida (https://github.com/x64dbg/x64dbgida) to import/export x64dbg databases.